# Find the price of an item in an order. The price of the item is the price negotiated for the order’s contract (5/day)

Tags: sql

I have an SQL project and that's one of the questions.
I have:

```
SELECT * FROM ToSupply
ORDER By ContractPrice;
```

This is my first SQL project, and 5/day means it should happen 5 times a day, how do I do that? Is there a method to repeat something after a set amount of time?

Comment: Please update your question to include sample data, the result you want to achieve based on that data and the logic needed to generate the target from the sample data

Comment: it should be done using a scheduler provided by the database you are using , for example in sql server you make a job and you schedule that job to be run 5 times a day or like Airflow as an advanced ETL scheduler .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the price of an item in an order for a particular day, you would need a column that expresses a DateTime value; let's call that 'OrderDay'.

If the price of the item is the price negotiated for the order’s contract, and only five orders are supplied per day, then this query is closer to what you desire:

```
SELECT AVG(ts.ContractPrice)/5
FROM ToSupply ts
JOIN 
    (
    SELECT OrderyDay, count(*)
    FROM ToSupply
    GROUP BY OrderDay
    HAVING count(*) = 5
    ) o5
ON ts.OrderDay = o5.OrderDay
GROUP BY ts.OrderDay
ORDER By AVG(ts.ContractPrice)/5;
```